How to apply camera calibration parameters to correct for alignment while stitching fisheye to equirectangle format?
I found a filter to convert dual fisheye to equirectangle format using v360 filter.
But if one the lens is tilted with regards to other lens then how to correct this alignment while converting fisheye to equirectangle format?
FFmpeg command for fisheye to equirectangle conversion:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "v360=dfisheye:e:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180" -y output.mp4

